# Backorder Size and Vintage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with fields such as:
OrderID, Supplier, Order_Date, Fulfillment_Date

Assumptions:

- OrderIDs are unique with no duplicates
- Every OrderID has an Order_Date, but not necessarily a
  Fulfillment_Date
- Every fulfilled order has a fulfillment date
- Unfulfilled orders are missing a fulfillment date

I want to calculate 2 things:

1. Number of unfulfilled orders per supplier by every date in a
   range. If there are no unfulfilled orders on a particular date for a particular supplier, mark it 0.
2. The total unfulfilled order age/vintage by supplier for every date. If there are no unfulfilled orders, mark it 0.

What I've tried:

- Some hack nested loops: it worked, but it's *really* slow

Some faked sample data

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'orderID': {0: 'ORDER3762642',
  1: 'ORDER3787490',
  2: 'ORDER3807252',
  3: 'ORDER3800697',
  4: 'ORDER3815902',
  5: 'ORDER3798524',
  6: 'ORDER3809288',
  7: 'ORDER3814427',
  8: 'ORDER3808695',
  9: 'ORDER3809680'},
 'supplier': {0: 'Under Armour',
  1: 'Nike',
  2: 'Nike',
  3: 'Nike',
  4: 'Nike',
  5: 'Adidas',
  6: 'Under Armour',
  7: 'Adidas',
  8: 'Adidas',
  9: 'Adidas'},
 'order_date': {0: '2022-01-06 17:27:00',
  1: '2022-01-20 12:32:00',
  2: '2022-02-03 12:18:00',
  3: '2022-01-31 09:08:00',
  4: '2022-02-08 08:43:00',
  5: '2022-01-28 11:10:00',
  6: '2022-02-04 12:38:00',
  7: '2022-02-07 15:05:00',
  8: '2022-02-04 03:39:00',
  9: '2022-02-04 17:08:00'},
 'fulfillment_date': {0: '2022-02-08 13:05:00',
  1: '2022-02-08 12:48:00',
  2: '2022-02-08 12:46:00',
  3: '2022-02-08 12:45:00',
  4: '2022-02-08 12:44:00',
  5: '2022-02-08 12:34:00',
  6: '2022-02-08 12:22:00',
  7: '2022-02-08 12:12:00',
  8: "",
  9: ""}})
```

To walk through an example of how one single order would calculate:

```
df[df["orderID"]=='ORDER3807252']

    orderID | supplier |    order_date |    fulfillment_date
    ORDER3807252 |  Nike |  2022-02-03 12:18:00 | 2022-02-08 12:46:00
```

Assuming we were just looking at this one single order, the output might look like:

```
Supplier | Date       | Unfulfilled Orders | Unfulfilled Vintage
-------- | ---------- |------------------- | -------------------
Nike     | 2022/02/03 | 0                  | 0
Nike     | 2022/02/04 | 1                  | 36 hours
Nike     | 2022/02/05 | 1                  | 60 hours
Nike     | 2022/02/06 | 1                  | 94 hours
Nike     | 2022/02/07 | 1                  | 118 hours
Nike     | 2022/02/08 | 0                  | 0
```

Comment: could you include a sample to play with?

Comment: Sample data or sample code? If sample data, which format would you prefer?

Comment: preferably a dictionary

Comment: Pardon my newbie dictionary

Comment: in your sample, every order seems to be fulfilled; is that right?

Comment: It was incorrect. I've updated the sample data. I'll note that I used empty text.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to `groupby` "supplier" and "order_date" to count the number of empty fulfillment_dates. So here goes:

For the first question:

```
unfulfilled_orders_per_day = df['fulfillment_date'].eq('').groupby([df['supplier'], df['order_date']]).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       supplier           order_date  fulfillment_date
0        Adidas  2022-01-28 11:10:00                 0
1        Adidas  2022-02-04 03:39:00                 1
2        Adidas  2022-02-04 17:08:00                 1
3        Adidas  2022-02-07 15:05:00                 0
4          Nike  2022-01-20 12:32:00                 0
5          Nike  2022-01-31 09:08:00                 0
6          Nike  2022-02-03 12:18:00                 0
7          Nike  2022-02-08 08:43:00                 0
8  Under Armour  2022-01-06 17:27:00                 0
9  Under Armour  2022-02-04 12:38:00                 0
```

For the second question:

```
total_unfulfilled_orders = df['fulfillment_date'].eq('').groupby(df['supplier']).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       supplier  fulfillment_date
0        Adidas                 2
1          Nike                 0
2  Under Armour                 0
```